# c++ virtual classes: interesting point

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, virtual-inheritance

Please tell me why the output is as below for the following program. I am not getting the virtual classes in c++. observe the below code:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(char c = 'a') : m_c(c) {}

public:
    char get_c() const { return m_c; }
    void set_c(char c) { m_c = c; }

private:
    char m_c;
};

class C: public B
{ };

class D: public B
{ };

class E
    : public C
    , public D
{ };

int main()
{
    E e;
    C &c = e;
    D &d = e;
    std::cout << c.get_c();
    d.set_c('b');
    std::cout << c.get_c() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

O/P:  aa
I expect output would be ab. What would be the reason for getting "aa"??

If i have c.set_c('b')  instead of d.set_c('b') then I will get O/P : "ab", Here also, I am not getting why is it as such. Both c, d are referring to one object only.

```
class C:virtual public B{};
class D:virtual public B{};
```

If the class C, class D are inherited virtually from B, then 
O/P would always be "ab"

Comment: C++ doesn't have "virtual classes".  We have "virtual inheritence", and "virtual functions"

Comment: The perplexing  thing is the second code snippet contains the answer to his dilemma, but the primary code sample doesn't use it. I.e. the OP answered his own question without putting it into practice.

Comment: thanks for your suggeston, I dont know that we have to accept it . I simply followed your answers. Sorry for that. I will accept now onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider `class C : public B` and `C* c = new C` then `c` point to an storage that begin with a `B` since `C*` is also `B*`. and this is `true` for `class D : public B`.

Now for `class E : public C, public D` and `E* e = new E()`. memory of `e` is something like:

```
{| B of C | other members of C }{| B of D | other members of D}
```

as you can see in above case we have 2 instance of `B` one for `C` and another for `D` and now it is obvious when you call `((D*)e)->set_c( 'b' )` you only change `B` instance of `D` and `B` instance of `C` will remain unchanged.

now when you say `class C : public virtual B`, C++ share `B` instance with any other class that virtually inherit from `B`. so in this case `e` is something like:

```
           | shared B |
    | C members | | D members |
```

and as you can see we have only one `B` so calling `((C*)e)->set_c` and `((D*)e)->set_c` will both act on same `B`.

Answer (score 9):

There are two copies of `B` in `E`, one via `C` and one via `D`. When you call `d.set_c('b')`, you're modifying the `m_c` in `D`'s `B`. When you call `c.get_c()`, you then get the `m_c` in `C`'s `B`, which hasn't changed.

When you make `C` and `D` inherit from `B` virtually, it solves the problem, because then there's only one copy of `B` in `E`.

This is relevant: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-inheritance-where.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem but your question contains the answer, declare B as a virtual base to both C and D and you get.

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
public:
    B(char c = 'a') : m_c(c) {}

public:
    char get_c() const { return m_c; }
    void set_c(char c) { m_c = c; }

private:
    char m_c;
};

// note virtual inheritance
class C: virtual public B
{ };

// note virtual inheritance
class D: virtual public B
{ };

class E
: public C
, public D
{ };

int main()
{
    E e;
    C &c = e;
    D &d = e;
    std::cout << c.get_c() << std::endl;;
    d.set_c('d');
    std::cout << c.get_c() << std::endl;
    c.set_c('c');
    std::cout << d.get_c() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which results in the output you want , doesn't it ??

```
a
d
c
```

Comment: this is because of virtual inheritance. But if it is not inherited virtually, then two copies are existed in the single object.

Comment: yeah, that would be why I put this here, and commented on the OP's mentioning it in his very question, then disregarding his own code and not doing it. This is how it is supposed to be done if you want a shared base instance, the question demonstrates knowledge of that, and then promptly didn't code it, which I found odd.